# degree of $f\circ g$

Tags: algebraic-topology, curves, covering-spaces

Let $f,g : \mathbb{S}^1 \to \mathbb{S}^1$ be two continuous maps where $\mathbb{S}^1$ is the unit circle. Prove that $\deg (f \circ g) = \deg f \deg g$.

I don't know at all how to do it : I first set a continuous function $\overline{f \circ g} : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f \circ g (e^{it})=e^{i \overline{f \circ g} (t)}$ for all $t \in [0,2\pi]$.

I've done the same for $f$ and $g$. Then $2 \pi \deg (f \circ g) = \overline{f \circ g} (2\pi)- \overline{f \circ g} (0)$ but I don't see any link with $\overline{f}$ nor $\overline{g}$.

I think all the thing is to prove that $\overline{f \circ g} = \bar f \circ \bar g $

Any help, or link ?

Thanks.

Comment: What is your definition of degree?  You've tagged in algebraic topology, and one of the definitions is given by the induced map on the homology, from which your statement is a direct result of functoriality.

Comment: It is algebraic geometry not topology sorry. 
My definition of the degree is what I said : it is the number $n$ such that $2\pi n = \overline{f} (a+ 2 \pi)+\bar f (a)$. (it does not depend on $a$)

Comment: No, algebraic geometry is totally inappropriate.

Comment: If it is then remove it, I don't mind where the question really belongs.

Comment: You mean $\bar f(a+2\pi)-\bar f(a)$, of course. ... So, can you show that $\bar f\circ\bar g$ satisfies the definition of $\overline{f\circ g}$?

Comment: Yes you are right it is a minus sign. In fact after re-writing it, I foud an answer, it is simple : $f(g(e^{it}))=f(e^{i \bar g (t)}) = e^{i \bar f \circ \bar g (t)}$.
It is really obvious sorry, but I can assure you I remained stuck on this for more than 3 hours !